# Range Space and Null Space proof, show that $y ∈ R(P)$ if and only if $y^T x = 0$ for every $x ∈ N (P)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm helping a friend of my family on some linear algebra. He presented me the following problem which I seem to not be able to prove right away, I've put thought into it and tried hard, but by now I request some help to see if someone shines some light on part (c).

Let $P$ be a non-negative definite $n·n$ matrix, and let $Q$ be an invertible, symmetric
$n·n$ matrix.
(a) Show that if $x^TP x = 0$ for some $x∈R^n$, then $P x = 0$.

This part seems pretty straight forward. I just distinguished the different cases possible.

i) $P=0$, then it is clear how $Px=0$

ii)$x=0$, then it is clear how $Px=0$

iii)$Px=0$

iv)$x^TP=0$, taking the transpose: $(x^TP)^T=P^Tx=Px=0$ since $P$ is a symmetric matrix (non-negative definite's definition implies symmetry).

(b) Give an example of an invertible, symmetric matrix $Q$ for which $x^TQx = 0$ for some nonzero $x$.

For this part, an example is enough. Although with some simple reasoning we can deduce how for any matrix who has eigenvalues with positive and negative values there exists a vector $x$ for which $x^TQx = 0$.

The example I used is a symmetric, diagonal matrix $Q$ with alternating $1$ and $-1$ in the diagonal. If $n$ is even all the $x_i$ must be the same, whilst if $n$ is odd then all the $x_i$ must be the same except the last $x_n$ which must be 0.

(c) The range space of a matrix $A$ (denoted $R(A)$ is the set of all vectors $y$ such that $y = Ax$ for some $x$. The null space of a matrix $A$ (denoted $N (A)$) is the set of all vectors $x$ such that $Ax = 0$. Show that $y ∈ R(P)$ if and only if $y^T x = 0$ for every $x ∈ N (P)$, where $R(P)$ and $N (P)$ are the rangespace and nullspace, respectively, of $P$. Keep in mind that our P is non-negative definite and hence symmetric. (Hint: expand vectors as linear combinations of eigenvectors.)

Okay, so this is the part for which I'm having trouble. The only if part seems pretty straight forward (unless my reasoning has no sense):

$y ∈ R(P)$ only if $y^T x = 0$

Since $y ∈ R(P)$, $y=Pu$ for some vector u. Then:

$y^T=(Pu)^T=u^TP^T=u^TP$ since $P$ is a symmetric matrix. Therefore:

$y^Tx=u^TPx$ where $x ∈ N (P)$.
Then, since $x ∈ N (P)$, $u^TPx=0$ because $Px=0$.

Now, the if part:

$y^T x = 0$ if $y ∈ R(P)$

I tried using contradiction, assuming $y\notin R(P)$. But imposing now that $y$ necessarily needs to be contained in $N(P)$ ($y \in N(P)$) wouldn't be precise since it's not part of the directions given on the problem. I can't seem to understand how to use the hint given. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: The first part is not complete; it could be $x^TPx=0$ with $x^TP\ne0$, $P\ne0$, $Px\ne0$ and $x\ne0$ and you should exclude this case. So you should assume $x^TPx=0$ and $Px\ne0$ for finding a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the hypothesis for the symmetry or definiteness of $P$ to show that $R(P)=N(P^T)^\perp$ (which reduces to $R(P)=N(P)^\perp$ if $P$ is symmetric).

If $x\in R(P)$ ($x=Pz$ for some $z$) and $y\in N(P^T)$, then $x^Ty=(Pz)^Ty=z^T(P^Ty)=0$ since $P^Ty=0$. Hence $x\in N(P^T)^\perp$ and we have $R(P)\subset N(P^T)^\perp$.

To show that $N(P^T)^\perp\subset R(P)$, you can show that $R(P)^\perp\subset N(P^T)$ (if $X\subset Y$ then $Y^\perp\subset X^\perp$ and $(X^\perp)^\perp=X$). If $x\in R(P)^\perp$, $x^Ty=0$ for all $y\in R(P)$. In other words, for all $z$, $x^T(Pz)=0$. With $z=P^Tx$, this gives $0=(P^Tx)^T(P^Tx)=\|P^Tx\|_2^2$ and hence $P^Tx=0$, that is, $x\in N(P^T)$.